# Does this replaceAll "sanitize" a path?

Tags: security

Written in Java.
I dont understand why this would be a security issue
if fName = ..project/blah/blah.exe

would this possibly open a file that might be malicious on a different directory that has the same name?

```
String sFileName = request.getParameter(“fName”);
sFileName = sFileName.replaceAll("/", “\\");
sFileName = sFileName.replaceAll(“..\\", "");
```

Comment: Why do *you* think it's a security vulnerability?

Comment: i dont think it is.. thats why i am asking if it is...

Comment: What prompted you to ask this question?

Comment: That depends on what you do with `sFileName`.

Comment: i would obviously open the sFileName

Comment: You would open it and do what with it? Read it and print its contents to the user, write it while the user can provide its new content, or what?

Comment: Who told you that this was a security vulnerability? What was their justification? You're not telling us everything.

Comment: @ealeon It’s about providing enough information for us to give you a satisfying answer. If you don’t have the time for that, you shouldn’t expect too much.

Comment: its a simple question... i dont need to write a 100-page essays justifying myself asking this question. Instead of asking why i am askin the question, why dont you answer the question. if you cant, move on.

Comment: @ealeon The *why* question is probably intended to get some reflections about the question from the enquirer himself. This to get some context information and to see if he did even take the time to think about the question by himself. Because SO is not intended to be a *just give me the damn answer* community. See also [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: you may be correct if the question itself is ambiguous or complex. However, this is a simple question and hence does not apply to such standard. If someone asks you what 1+1 is, you obviously won't ask him/her why. Yes i would ask the question because i didnt think about it at all and I just want the answer. Yeah you are right. haha so funny...

Comment: @ealeon If you don’t respect the people that you are asking for help, then SO is not the right place. And respecting them begins right with phrasing the question in a way that it doesn’t leave open questions. If you can’t, then be at least be to answer them. It’s still their time that you are wasting by not providing enough information. If you’re not, then, indeed, move on.

Answer (score 5):

If you use `sFileName` directly, the most obvious problem is that you don't deal with `absolute paths`. For examle, your input could be;

```
C:\Users\Test\secret.txt
```

and you'd replace nothing, just open it right away.

Another one would be that the *replace itself* could create a path that has `..` in it. Consider for example `....\\secret.txt` that would be replaced to `..\secret.txt`.

Comment: ....\\secret.txt that would be replaced to ..\secret.txt. I dont understand why this replacement would be bad.

Comment: @ealeon `....\secret.txt` is an *invalid* path, but the replacements would result in `..\secret.txt` which is a *valid relative path*. Now, imagine if the web server (or whatever it is) displays the contents of this path that it opens -- no more secrets :(

Answer (score 3):

That is possibly insecure; or, rather, the replacements in the post *add no security*.

Imagine this input:

```
..../some/sensitive/relativepath
```

Which would have this output (this is the string value, not a string literal):

```
..\some\senstive\relativepath
```

That is, the provided code *does not guard against carefully constructed - e.g. "hacker" - input*; as demonstrated it is trivial to bypass the "relative path removal".

It also does not guard against absolute paths:

```
\some\sensitive\absolutepath
```

Comment: okay so it will be ...\\some\sensitive\\relativepath and?

Comment: And .. what's the question? If the value is blindly used an attacker could get access to resources not meant to be accessed.

Comment: but I (the programmer) am the one whos is making the replacement. and there wouldnt be a place that has \\ in any OS, correct?

Comment: @ealeon Windows will quite happily work with \ in path names.

Comment: @ealeon "\\" in a string literal is a string equivalent to \ (a string of one character) - since the string literal is just a Java source code artifact, I have only used the *real string value* in this reply and all comments.